# Css3 Responsive menu dropdown error while resize

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am new in css3 responsive design and have a question. i have a dropdown responsive menu, it is working fine but when i resize browser window as per mobile/tablet size and then click on menu, it populate dropdown and in same state if i again expand browser window to full desktop size, i see all my dropdown scattered on screen and when i refresh the page then i become ok. Please advise.

my css is

```
body {
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
  /* needed for checkbox hack */
  background: white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bugfix {
  from {
    padding: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
/* needed for checkbox hack */
h1, p {
  color: white;
}

#nav {
  position: relative;
}
#nav ul {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  list-style:none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #1c76ba;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #175f97;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #18a2e7;
}
#nav ul li:last-of-type a {
  border-right: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px;
}
#nav ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}
#nav ul li ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 3.125em;
}
#nav input.trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
#nav input.trigger:checked ~ ul, #nav input.trigger:checked ~ ul li ul {
  display: block !important;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  #nav input.trigger:checked ~ ul, #nav input.trigger:checked ~ ul li ul {
    /* older flexbox */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    /* newer flexbox */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
#nav label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 2em;
  padding: .45em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #20598d;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #bfe1fb;
}
#nav label:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: .2em;
  content: "\2261";
  font-size: 1.8em;
  color: white;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  #nav ul {
    /* older flexbox */
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    flex-direction: -ms-row;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    /* newer flexbox */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  #nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    /* older flexbox */
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    /* newer flexbox */
    flex: 1;
  }
  #nav ul li ul {
    display: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.0625em;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 12.5em;
    z-index: 200;
  }
  #nav ul li ul li {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #nav ul li ul li ul {
    z-index: 300;
    top: 0px;
    left: 12.4em;
  }
  #nav ul li ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
  }
  #nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block !important;
  }
  #nav label {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a link of the implementation of the dropdown

Comment: You can see the implementation there http://www.oriel-tech.com/dropdownmenu.aspx

Comment: Try changing your jquery to `$('#mainNavButton').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    menu.slideToggle();
                });` instead of `$('#openup').on('click', function (e) {.....
`

Comment: You are right @mannu-nayyar, that error has gone but another error occurred that dropdown menu open with double click now on first time only after resize browser then it works fine with single click. You can see the implementation on above url